# Why is the setname function running?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a multipurpose program using Python3. 
I have tested def weather(): and it works to show weather data for a given zip code. The program is supposed to never end unless the user types STOP.
The setname(): function is only supposed to run if the user types 'name' and 'my' or 'set'. When I run the program it asks, "What would you like to be called" no matter what I type. I tried even just typing z, but it still somehow started up the setname(): function. Please forgive me as this is my first time asking on stack.

What is causing the setname(): function to activate?

```
def weather():
    import requests
    wgURL = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/0def10027afaebb7/forecast/q/f/place.json"
    print('What place are you looking for?')
    wgURL = wgURL.replace('place', input())
    r = requests.get(wgURL)
    data = r.json()

    for day in data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:
        print (day['date']['weekday'] + ":")
        print ("Conditions: ", day['conditions'])
        print ("High: ", day['high']['fahrenheit'] + "F", "Low: ", day['low']['fahrenheit'] + "F", '\n')

def setname():
    print('What would you like to be called?')
    username = input()
    print('Okay, I will now call you ' + username) 

username = 'Anthony'

print('Done')

run = True
while run == True:
    request = input()
    if request == 'hi' or 'hello':
        print('Hello there ' + username)
    if 'weather' in request:
        weather()
    if 'name' and 'my' or 'set' in request:
        setname()
    if request == 'STOP':
        run = False
```

[Here is a screenshot from IDLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq9VC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand how `in` works. Since `in` binds more tightly than either `and` or `or`, it turns out that `'name' and 'my' or 'set' in request` means `('name' and 'my') or ('set' in request)`. This always evaluates to true, since `'name'` is truthy and `'my'` is truthy (both are non-empty strings).

Do this instead:

```
if ('name' in request and 'my' in request) or ('set' in request):
    setname()
```

You likewise have a problem with `request == 'hi' or 'hello'`: this means `(request == 'hi') or 'hello'`, which is always true, since `'hello'` is truthy. What you probably want here is:

```
if request == 'hi' or request == 'hello':
```

Consult the [operator precedence table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) if it strikes your fancy.